# How to bind these in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios

How does the ObjectiveC code below translate into MonoTouch?

```
@interface PSPDFBookmarkViewController : UITableViewController <PSPDFStyleable>
- (instancetype)initWithDocument:(PSPDFDocument *)document;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isInPopover;
@end
```

- I don't really know what to do with the `instancetype` thingy (what is this?)
- What is `id<PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate>`.
- What to do with the `PSPDFStyleable`?

This is what I think would be the result:

```
[BaseType(typeof(UITableViewController)]
    interface PSPDFBookmarkViewController
    {
    void InitWithDocument(PSPDFDocument document);
    [NullAllowed]
    PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate Delegate { get; set; }
    bool IsInPopover { get; set; }
    }
```

And what about this interface?

```
@interface PSPDFBookmarkViewController (SubclassingHooks)
- (void)createBarButtonItems;
@end
```

What is the `(SubclassingHooks)` about and what is its C# cousin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many questions... here's a few answers:

ObjectiveC `init*` selectors are .NET constructors. So:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDocument:(PSPDFDocument *)document;
```

should be like:

```
[Export ("initWithDocument:")]
IntPtr Constructor (PSPDFDocument document);
```

and your other C# bindings are missing their `[Export]` attributes. E.g.

```
[Export ("isInPopover")]
bool IsInPopover { get; set; }
```

Other questions:

`<PSPDFStyleable>` is a Objective-C protocol, which is very similar to .NET interfaces. Now if you don't need `PSPDFStyleable` then you do not have to bind it.

> What is `id<PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate>`.

That's an instance that implements `PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate`. You would normally bind this as `PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate` for the `Delegate` property and also add a `WeakDelegate` so any `NSObject` that implement the *right* selectors can be used. E.g.

```
[Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)][NullAllowed]
NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }

[Wrap ("WeakDelegate")]
PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate Delegate { get; set; }
```

You'll need to add `Delegates=new string [] { "WeakDelegate" }` to your `[BaseType]` attribute. Also add `Events=` if you want to turn the delegate members into events. E.g.

```
[BaseType (typeof (UITableViewController), Delegates=new string [] { "WeakDelegate" }, Events=new Type [] {typeof (PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate)})]
```

`(SubclassingHooks)` is an Objective-C category, which is very similar to .NET extensions methods. That requires a bit of manual bindings with the existing generator.

Finally make sure to read the [binding documents](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_Objective-C_Libraries) that are available on Xamarin documentation portal. It's not very complicated (your sample hits a lot of cases for very few lines) but there's a lot of data to digest (even more if you do not know Objective-C very well).

Comment: True. The Exports() I know but I forgot to type. 
The c'tor was valuable information. Remains:  what is id<PSPDFBookmarkViewControllerDelegate>? How to deal with the PSPDStyleable protocol? And last: how to bind the category (SubclassingHooks)? A lot, I know...

Comment: Found one more. Categories = class extensions. Covered here:  http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_Objective-C_Libraries

Comment: @Krumelur I expended my original answer with more details - but you found the link that will explain all of it (in more depths).

Comment: There are a lot of special cases indeed...I feel kind of lost at the moment. And I haven't even been trying to understand things like "[Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]" or "[PostGet ("Documents")]". Still a long way to perfection. But in the end it will all work.